# CSS : Div coming as next line

Tags: css, html

I have this HTML in my page

```
  <div id='masterDIV'>
    <div id='divItemNumber'>23</div>
   <div id='divDesc'>This is my desc content</div>
  </div>
```

and my Style

```
.divItemNumber
 {
 width:25px;
 margin-left:0px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
 }
.divDesc
{
 width:255px;
 float:right;
 padding-left:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 margin-top:0px;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

But the second div is coming as the next line. I want this to be displayed adjucent right after the first div (divITemNumber)

This problem comes in IE 6.0 only .in firefox its rendering properly

Can any one help me ?

Comment: I really wish IE 6 would die.

Comment: I also wish that all browsers could merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS div classes:

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 4):

One problem is that your CSS selector is not correct.

You have to use

```
#divDesc
```

instead of

```
.divDesc
```

to select the div with id divDesc

Read

[ID selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing you CSS so that the first div is `float: left` and the second is normal.

Alternatively, changing the first div from a block type element to an inline type element (`display: inline`) should fix the problem.